# How to set the master page dynamically using http handler?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I knew, we can set the master page dynamically using Page_PreInit method of each page... but if i want to set the master page dynamically for more than 10 pages, changing the code in each page is not good idea....Did anyone tried using ASP.NET Http Handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can use a base class/page which inherits from asp.net `Page` and have your 10 pages inherit from that base class. You can set the `masterpage` in the overloaded `PreInit` event on the base class.